# Touchscreen doesn't work after update from 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: asus, 15.04, touchscreen

My touchscreen worked fine with 14.04, but stopped to respond after I updated the system to 15.04.

The laptop is ASUS ux302lg.

```
$ xinput
Virtual core pointer           id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad   id=14  [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer id=11  [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard          id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                   id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                   id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                id=9  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                   id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys            id=12 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=13    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please give output of "xinput" command.

Comment: Did it work with 14.10?

Comment: @xangua I skipped 14.10

Comment: So by update you mean you did a fresh 15.04 install?

Comment: Try to boot from 15.04 LiveCD and test the touchscreen.

Comment: @xangua now I'm not sure. If it's not possible to update from pre-previous version, then I had 14.10 and it worked